# Keras, how to pass extra argument to custom loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a model with multiple outputs like:

```py
model_in = Input((None, None, 3))
out_1 = Dense(10)(model_in)
out_2 = Dense(20)(model_in)
model = keras.Model(model_in, [out_1, out_2])

model.compile('adam', loss = [loss_fn_1, loss_fn_2])
```

And for each training sample, I have a mask which should be used in my custom loss function (actually my data generator produces this mask based on input sample). So for each sample I have one input, two outputs and a mask that should be used in loss function. My question is how should I pass the mask to appropriate  loss function (I use different loss function for each output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loss function has three arguments, so it can not be used with keras `compile()`, `fit()` (https://keras.io/api/losses/).

You have two options:

1. create a custom loop or
2. create a custom layer and use `add_loss()`.